# How to change .com domain to .eth?

Tags: ens, eth-domain

I want to have a .eth domain and I want to link .com website with .eth website. I mean by typing example.eth, people can reach example.com. I look around on the internet but it seemed a little bit complicated. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`.eth` domains signify redirection to an Ethereum address. On Brave Browser (and other similar browsers), typing in `example.eth` will lead you to a website. This will not work by default on most browsers, even Brave Mobile.

To link a `.com` website, you need to head over to dashboard ([https://app.ens.domains/name/{EXAMPLEUSER}.eth](https://app.ens.domains/name/%7BEXAMPLEUSER%7D.eth)) - connect your wallet, edit content and URL as needed.

More on this [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/decentralizing-your-website-f5bca765f9ed).